# Never fall behind for simple random walk

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question about the "never fall behind" for one-dimensional simple random walk.

For simple random walk, Let $S_{n}=\sum_{j}X_{j}$ where $X_{j}=+1$ with probability $p$ and $X_{j}=-1$ with probability $q$. By "never fall behind", we want to find $$\Bbb P(S_{1}\geq 0,S_{2}\geq 0,\dots,S_{n}=x)$$ where $x=1,2,\dots,n$.

If we let $A_{n}=\sum_{j} \Bbb 1_{\{X_{j}=+1\}}$ and $B_{n}=\sum_{j} \Bbb 1_{\{X_{j}=-1\}}$

Then
$\Bbb P(S_{1}\geq 0,S_{2}\geq 0,\dots,S_{n}=x)=p^{A_{n}}q^{B_{n}}$ times numbers of paths from$(0,0)$ to $(n,x)$ that do not fall below the axis

But my note says number of paths from$(0,0)$ to $(n,x)$ that do not fall below the axis=the number of paths from $(-1,-1)$ to $(n,x)$ that lie strictly lie above $-1$.

Could someone help me explain it? I think it should be the number of paths from $(1,-1)$ to $(n,x)$ that lie strictly lie above $-1$ by reflection principle. I don't know how $(-1,-1)$ comes into the picture

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb Z$ then $x \ge 0 \iff x \gt -1$.  Any path from $(-1,-1)$ to $(n,x)$ which does not hit $-1$  must start by going to $(0,0)$ and then not fall below $0$

Comment: @Henry Is there something wrong with my argument? If $S_{1} \geq 0$ it means $X_{1}$ must be 1, then we only need to count paths from $(1.-1)$ to $(n,x)$ which lie strictly above $-1$

Comment: no - I think you could say it is the number of such paths from $(-1,-1)$ to $(n,x)$ or from $(0,0)$ to $(n,x)$ or from $(+1,+1)$ to $(n,x)$.  Try it with $n=3$ and $x=1$ and I think you want to get an answer of two such paths while going from $(1,-1)$ to $(3,1)$ has five such paths.  And starting from $(-1,-1)$ allows you to use Bertrand's ballot theorem